# Does a bipartite graph without perfect matching exist?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I know that not all bipartite graphs have perfect matching, but I am having trouble coming up with an example (I'm a visual learner). Can someone give me a visual example of a bi[artite graph without perfect matching?

Comment: Any bipartite graph with an odd number of vertices. Any graph with no edges, e.g., two vertices and no edges. Any complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ with $m\ne n$. The graph with vertices $a,b,c,d,e,f$ and edges $ad,ae,af,bf,cf$. I can't help wondering where you were looking, that you had trouple coming up with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a chain graph with 3 vertices and 2 edges:

$$ \bullet - \circ - \bullet $$

If you use the left edge, then you cannot use the right one (because you cannot use the white vertex twice), and similarly if you use the right edge, then you cannot use the left edge. Either way, a black vertex will be left unmatched.

Comment: Reject the edit. It doesn't work on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a connected example with partitions of equal size:

[image]